For every integer $r>1$, there is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $\mathbb{Z} / r \mathbb{Z}$.
I want to show that for every integer $r>1$, there is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $\mathbb{Z} / r \mathbb{Z}$.
I'm not really sure how to do this - I know that if $p$ is prime, then $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) / \mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z} / (p-1) \mathbb{Z}$.
But for most $r$, I have no idea how to begin.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#A_simple_example:_cyclic_groups

There's a proof here as well that avoids Dirichlet's theorem.

The proof in the duplicate works also for non-square free orders. For $n=p^m,2p^m$ or $n=1,2,4$ the group $U(n)$ is cyclic, and ${\rm Gal}(\Bbb Q(\zeta_n),\Bbb Q)\cong U(n)$.
